# Add in missing decimal (001=0.01 and 01=0.1)

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

I have a vector of strings `a<-data.table(value=("001","01"))` that really should be decimals (0.01 and 0.1) and would liked to split the strings at the first 0 and add in a decimal before it.

I can split the string and get a list

```
A<-strsplit(a$value, "(?=[0])", perl = TRUE)
```

so I can envisage doing paste0(x[[1]][1],".",x[[1]][2]) inside a function but I'm getting a bit stuck with how to refer to the indices:

```
dFun<-function(){
  as.numeric(paste0(x[[1]][1],".",x[[1]][2]))
}


purrr::map_df(.x=1:2,.f=dFun)
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
> a[, value := gsub("(?=1)", ".", value, perl = TRUE)][]
   value
1:  00.1
2:   0.1
```

or

```
> a[, value := sub("(^0)", "\\1.", value)][]
   value
1:  0.01
2:   0.1
```

or

```
> a[, value := as.numeric(sub("(^0)", "\\1.", value))][]
   value
1:  0.01
2:  0.10
```

Comment: Thomas thank you very much indeed to looking at this so quickly. As you have already spotted, I made a mistake with the splitting.

Comment: @HCAI Yes, I see that. You can check my answer, which may include the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since `sub` will replace only first occurrence, you can do -

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(value=c("001","01"))
a[, value := as.numeric(sub('0', '0.', value))]
a

#   value
#1:  0.01
#2:  0.10
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
a[, value := as.numeric(str_replace(value, '0', '0.'))]
> a
   value
1:  0.01
2:  0.10
```

`